# Play 3gpp file using Media Object in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, media

The algorithm of my app:

1) Record an audio file using PhoneGap CaptureAudio.

2) Store the file on the server using FileTransfer.

3) Play the file using Media object.

Step 1 is accomplished and I get a recording-XXXXX.3gpp file.

Step 2 is accomplished and the recording-XXXXX.3gpp file is uploaded to my server.

Step 3 is where the problem lies. Media object errors out when opening 3gpp file

```
   var my_media = new Media("http://myserver/getfile.aspx?file=filepath/recording-XXXXX.3gpp", function() { 
           console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }, function(){
           alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
           'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    });     
    my_media.play();
```

But if I change the query to a mp3 file, the media object works as required.

I am not sure what is going wrong. One thing, I can do is create the .3gpp to .mp3 but that option is final resort.

Please help me with this.

I am using PhoneGap 2.4.0 on Android Tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the resolution.

When you are uploading the file to the server, upload the file as .wav or .mp3 extension instead of .3gpp. Rename the recorded file from .3gpp to .wav or .mp3

And when you provide the URL to the Media object, the player streams the file and begins playing it.

Though the file, uploaded to the server and extension changed to either .wav or .mp3, doesn't play on desktop using Windows Media Play if no compatible plugins are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the extension of .3gpp instead of .3gp?

And are you sure that IIS is serving the 3gp file back and with the correct header of `video/3gpp`? What happens if you navigate to the url for the file from your desktop browser instead of the device?

IIS might not be aware of the MIME-type for 3gp using the .3gpp extension and therefore won't serve the files, since by default IIS won't serve unrecognized file extensions for security reasons.

And if mp3 is a registered MIME-type but 3gp isn't so that would explain why one works but not the other.

[Follow the instructions here to add the 3gp MIME type:](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/05/13/3gp-files-not-served-by-iis.aspx)

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.3gp',mimeType='audio/3gpp']"
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan for input. I checked again and the PhoneGap captureAudio function provides a file with .3gpp and not .3gp. I checked with my IIS server and ran tried to access the file through a browser, the browser downloaded the required file on my desktop. It seems like the browser does not have required plugins to run the .3gpp extension and hence it downloads the file on the desktop. But I assume the Android system should have all the plugins required to run the .3gpp extension.